# How to allocate ION's memory of predefined heap type?

Tags: linux, kernel

In my case, I am allocating memory like this:

```
    struct ion_allocation_data arg_alloc;

    arg_alloc.len = len;
    arg_alloc.heap_mask = heap_mask;
    arg_alloc.flags = flags;
    arg_alloc.fd = 0;

    ret = ioctl(client, ION_IOC_ALLOC_V1, &arg_alloc);
```

In kernel sources I found that heap id is calculated as:

```
    heap_id = 1 << MAGIC_NUMBER;
```

MAGIC_NUMBER here is heap id (which is not equal to heap type).
This MAGIC_NUMBER is calculated during kernel's boot, thanks to Laura Abbott:

> SHA 2f87f50b
>     by Laura Abbott, 04/18/2017 09:27 PM
>     committed by Greg Kroah-Hartman, 04/18/2017 09:43 PM
>     parent eb9751db
>
> staging: android: ion: Rework heap registration/enumeration
>
> The current model of Ion heap registration  is based on the outdated
>     model of board files. The replacement for board files (devicetree)
>     isn't a good replacement for what Ion wants to do. In actuality, Ion
>     wants to show what memory is available in the system for something else
>     to figure out what to use. Switch to a model where Ion creates its
>     device unconditionally and heaps are registed as available regions.
>     Currently, only system and CMA heaps are converted over to the new
>     model. Carveout and chunk heaps can be converted over when someone wants
>     to figure out how.
>
> Signed-off-by: Laura Abbott 
>     Signed-off-by: Greg Kroah-Hartman

I want to use DMA heap. Type of this heap is defined in enumeration:

```
    typedef enum
    {
    ION_HEAP_TYPE_SYSTEM,
    ION_HEAP_TYPE_SYSTEM_CONTIG,
    ION_HEAP_TYPE_CARVEOUT,
    ION_HEAP_TYPE_CHUNK,
    ION_HEAP_TYPE_DMA,
    ION_HEAP_TYPE_CUSTOM, /*
    * must be last so device specific heaps always
    * are at the end of this enum
    */
    } ion_heap_type;
```

Now is a problem, ION_HEAP_TYPE_DMA is enumerated here as 4, and this number in not heap id. Right heap id mask, which corresponds to this heap type, in my case, is equal to (1 << 1) (once more, thanks to Laura).

So, again, the question is: "How to allocate ION's memory of predefined heap type? How to allocate the same memory on different platforms?".

Comment: As I can see, this thread is dead. Can anyone give me advice about how to contact  Linux developers?

Comment: I wrote an e-mail to Abbot, but she was ignoring me. It's pity. Anyway I found the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ION's driver contains ioctl's command "ION_IOC_HEAP_QUERY" argument which may be used to get information about heaps (name, type, id, etc.), enabled on concrete platform.
Example of implementation was found on the following [link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/libion/ion.c):

```
int ion_query_heap_cnt(int fd, int* cnt) {
    int ret;
    struct ion_heap_query query;
    memset(&query, 0, sizeof(query));
    ret = ion_ioctl(fd, ION_IOC_HEAP_QUERY, &query);
    if (ret < 0) return ret;
    *cnt = query.cnt;
    return ret;
}

int ion_query_get_heaps(int fd, int cnt, void* buffers) {
    int ret;
    struct ion_heap_query query = {
        .cnt = cnt, .heaps = (uintptr_t)buffers,
    };
    ret = ion_ioctl(fd, ION_IOC_HEAP_QUERY, &query);
    return ret;
}
```

Example of use for this API is found [here](https://android.googlesource.com/device/linaro/hikey/+/refs/heads/master/gralloc/alloc_device.cpp):

```
static int find_ion_heap_id(int ion_client, char* name)
{
    int i, ret, cnt, heap_id = -1;
    struct ion_heap_data *data;
    ret = ion_query_heap_cnt(ion_client, &cnt);
    if (ret)
    {
        AERR("ion count query failed with %s", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    data = (struct ion_heap_data *)malloc(cnt * sizeof(*data));
    if (!data)
    {
        AERR("Error allocating data %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    ret = ion_query_get_heaps(ion_client, cnt, data);
    if (ret)
    {
        AERR("Error querying heaps from ion %s", strerror(errno));
    }
    else
    {
        for (i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
            struct ion_heap_data *dat = (struct ion_heap_data *)data;
            if (strcmp(dat[i].name, name) == 0) {
                heap_id = dat[i].heap_id;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (i > cnt)
        {
            AERR("No System Heap Found amongst %d heaps\n", cnt);
            heap_id = -1;
        }
    }
    free(data);
    return heap_id;
}
```

Following function may be simply rewritten to get heap_id from heap_type.

After we've got heap_id we need to calculate:

```
heap_mask = (1 << heap_id);
```